# cin.clear() and cin.ignore() won't work

Tags: c++, string, performance, function

I did a lot of research about this issue and found some answers and corrected my code but I still can't get `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()` to work. This is the part of my code I am referring to:

```
if(cityname1 == "Error" || cityname2 == "Error")
{
    cout << "**********ERROR! PLEASE ENTER 0-5 FOR YOU LOCATIONS**********" << endl << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    detailLoop();
}
else
{
    cout << "The distance from " << cityname1 << " to " << cityname2;
    cout << " is approximately " << cityarray[start][finish] << " miles." << endl << endl;
}
```

The error message is output if the user enters a number other than 0-5, but if they enter a character, the code goes into an infinite loop.  After doing the research, I feel like this code should work but unfortunately I can't get it to.  Also, I am a beginner so if anyone has advice on the way this is written, please criticize!!!  Here is the entire function if that helps.  I did `#include<limits>`.

```
void detailLoop()
{
//initializes array(letters in comments stand for city;
//array values are the distances)
int cityarray[6][6] = {
    //DB-DB,DB-G,DB-J,DB-M,DB-Tall,DB-Tampa
    0,97,90,268,262,130,

    //G-DB,G-G,G-J,G-M,G-Tall,G-Tampa
    97,0,74,337,144,128,

    //J-DB,J-G,J-J,J-M,J-Tall,J-Tampa
    90,74,0,354,174,201,

    //M-DB,M-G,M-J,M-M,M-Tall,M-Tampa
    268,337,354,0,475,269,

    //Tall-DB,Tall-G,Tall-J,Tall-M,Tall-Tall,Tall-Tampa
    262,144,174,475,0,238,

    //Tampa-DB,Tampa-G,Tampa-J,Tampa-M,Tampa-Tall,Tampa-Tampa
    130,128,201,269,238,0
    };

//starting location
int start = 0;
//destination
int finish = 0;
//strings used to print city names
string cityname1;
string cityname2;
//menu block
cout << "Choose locations from the menu below:" << endl;
cout << "0 - Daytona Beach" << endl;
cout << "1 - Gainesville" << endl;
cout << "2 - Jacksonville" << endl;
cout << "3 - Miami" << endl;
cout << "4 - Tallahassee" << endl;
cout << "5 - Tampa" << endl << endl;

//user input for starting city
cout << "Enter your starting location: > "; cin >> start;

//user input for ending city
cout << "Enter your destination: > "; cin >> finish; cout << endl;

//assigns names to cityname1 so it can be printed
switch(start)
{
case 0:
    cityname1 = "Daytona Beach";
    break;
case 1:
    cityname1 = "Gainesville";
    break;
case 2:
    cityname1 = "Jacksonville";
    break;
case 3:
    cityname1 = "Miami";
    break;
case 4:
    cityname1 = "Tallahassee";
    break;
case 5:
    cityname1 = "Tampa";
    break;
default:
    cityname1 = "Error";
    break;
}

//assigns names to cityname2 so it can be printed
switch(finish)
{
case 0:
    cityname2 = "Daytona Beach";
    break;
case 1:
    cityname2 = "Gainesville";
    break;
case 2:
    cityname2 = "Jacksonville";
    break;
case 3:
    cityname2 = "Miami";
    break;
case 4:
    cityname2 = "Tallahassee";
    break;
case 5:
    cityname2 = "Tampa";
    break;
default:
    cityname2 = "Error";
    break;
}

if(cityname1 == "Error" || cityname2 == "Error")
{
    cout << "**********ERROR! PLEASE ENTER 0-5 FOR YOU LOCATIONS**********" << endl << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    detailLoop();
}
else
{
    cout << "The distance from " << cityname1 << " to " << cityname2;
    cout << " is approximately " << cityarray[start][finish] << " miles." << endl << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with `clear()` and `ignore()` and not in some other assumption your code makes? Because if you *are* sure, you should have a *much shorter*, compilable example of just a few lines, which everyone here could use to reproduce your problem. (Without going into city names, distance calculation etc.) We call that a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If the user enters a non-number in `start`, it will be zero. It will not be "some value that is not one of those I later consider valid".

Comment: And the lesson learned here: to process a line of text entered by a user, always use `std::getline()`, and you won't have to screw around with trying to clear and reset a failed input stream. That's what `std::getline()` is for, and not the `>>` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `cin.fail()` along with your conditions

```
if(cin.fail()||cityname1 == "Error" || cityname2 == "Error")
{
cout << "**********ERROR! PLEASE ENTER 0-5 FOR YOU LOCATIONS**********" << endl << endl;
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
detailLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found in the end all of these typed readers to be useless and insane to try to make work for reading interactive input. You basically end up fighting with the terminal and the input buffer.

cin.clear() does not do anything rational when dealing with standard input and parse-reprompt for interactive sessions. You should not be calling it.

Rewrite everything in terms of cin.getline() and parsing the resulting string and you will be able to understand the failure modes and fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code [works fine](http://ideone.com/tlCZeI), *if* your `main()` looks like this:

```
int main() { detailLoop(); }
```

I suspect that you are calling `detailLoop` from within a loop which would cause an infinite loop.